# Uploading photo from react native(expo) camera to aws s3 after resized by lambda

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, expo, aws-api-gateway

**Progress until now**
I have created an app.
captured image from app has a object like this

`

```
{
  "height": 4000,
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fimage-upload-4ceaf845-d42a-4a1d-b1be-5a3f9cfd10ba/Camera/e3d441b6-2664-4c30-a093-35f7f0f09488.jpg",
  "width": 3000,
}
```

`

I have made an end point in api gateway and api gateway connects to a lambda and i'm sending above data to my backend as `

```
axios
      .post(uploadEndPoint, capturedImage, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
```

`
i get captured data in my lambda

first i'm trying to save in s3 with out resizing like this if this works then i will go for resizing.

```
`

import Responses from '../utils/responses';
    import * as fileType from 'file-type';
    import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
    import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
    
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    
    const allowedMimes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'];
    
    export const handler = async (event) => {
      console.log('event>>', JSON.parse(event.body));
      try {
        const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    
        if (!body) {
          return Responses._400({ message: 'incorrect body on request' });
        }
    
        let imageData = body;
        console.log('imageData>>', imageData);
       
        const buffer = Buffer.from(imageData, 'base64');
        console.log('buffer>>', buffer);
        const fileInfo = await fileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
        console.log(fileInfo);
        const detectedExt = fileInfo.ext;
        const detectedMime = fileInfo.mime;
    
        console.log('detectedExt>>', detectedExt);
        console.log('detectedMime>>', detectedMime);
    
        if (!allowedMimes.includes(detectedMime)) {
          return Responses._400({ message: 'mime is not allowed ' });
        }
    
        const name = uuid();
        const key = `${name}.${detectedExt}`;
    
        console.log(`writing image to bucket called ${key}`);
    
        await s3
          .putObject({
            Body: buffer,
            Key: key,
            ContentType: detectedMime,
            Bucket: process.env.imageUploadBucket,
            ACL: 'public-read',
          })
          .promise();
    
        const url = `https://${process.env.imageUploadBucket}.s3-${process.env.region}.amazonaws.com/${key}`;
        return Responses._200({
          imageURL: url,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    
        return Responses._400({
          message: error.message || 'failed to upload image',
        });
      }
    };
```

`

fileInfo shows undifined

**Things i want**
Resize image and upload to s3 by that lambda